# meaning of second

Tags: meaning

"I saw your picture and I could tell from the second I saw it it´s not Mr. X."

What is meant with second? Second like "time second / moment" or second like 2. (like first, third, fourth,...)?

So which sentence has the same meaning?

"I saw your picture and I could tell from the **moment** I saw it it´s not Mr. X." or

"I saw your picture and I could tell from the **2.** I saw it it´s not Mr. X."

Comment: It has roughly the same meaning as "moment".  Not literally however many vibrations of the cesium atom, but a brief interval of time.

Comment: I dont understand your last sentence?

Comment: So do you think second has here the same meaning as moment or not?

Comment: The "second", the official unit of time, is defined as the time required for 9 billion vibrations of the cesium atom, or some such, to provide a precise, reproducible value for physicists and engineers.  The word "second", in the sense used by your example, is not nearly that precise, but merely means a "moment" or a brief interval of time.

Comment: Yes thats the definition of a time second, but what about the context?

Comment: Does it also mean a "time second" or does it mean "2." as the ordinal value?

Comment: **It means the same as "moment", which is a brief interval of time.**

Answer (score 2):

In that context it means that the author instantly knew it was not Mr. X.
It is referring to the unit of time (not the ordinal value 'second', meaning after the first and before the third).

Your first offered sentence has the same meaning.

Comment: So you think second has here the same meaning as "moment"?

Answer (score 0):

Second refers to the unit of time. Since "second" refers to the smallest unit of time which has a name, it conveys the idea of a very short interval elapsing between seeing the picture and recognizing. It didn't take an hour; it didn't take a minute, it only took a second. So in the same second (thus in the same moment) I saw the picture, I also recognized it was not Mr. X.

Comment: Millisecond, microsecond, nanosecond, picosecond... femtosecond...